# OpenNetCF And MemoryMappedFile

Tags: compact-framework, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files, opennetcf

I´m using OpenNetCF in my Win CE app.

I need to use a shared memory solution, and I thought about Using the MemoryMappedFile.

But https://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/ does not show how to use it.

I mean, it´s clear to me how can I create a mapped file in one place. But is not clear to me how can I 
open this mapped file in another place.

Does anyone has a example?
Or Does anyone has another solution for shared memory?

Comment: @ctacke has an example on the opennetcf blog: http://blog.opennetcf.com/2011/11/15/sdf-sample-ipc-with-memory-mapped-files/

Comment: Thanks! But i think, now, that this may be not what I need. Mapped Files works with threads in the same process. I need something that could work with different proccess. (Like 2 apps that need to access a common data).

Comment: The blog post is about communication between processes.

Comment: The MMF can definitely be used for multiple processes to share data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another MemoryMapped file usage with example for CF: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79069/How-to-use-a-memory-mapped-file-with-Csharp-in-Win

Unfortunately ctacke's example is v.e.r.y. s.l.o.w.